# Unable to use the class defined in src in vars of jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, groovy

Here is the folder structure in my shared library repo:

```
$ tree src vars
src
├── org
    └── common.groovy

vars
├── testSrc.groovy
```

src has:

```
$ cat src/org/common.groovy
package org.common

class CommonFuncs {
    def sayHi() {
        echo "Hi from CommonFuncs!"
    }

    def sayHello(str) {
        echo "Hello ${str}"
    }
}
```

and vars:

```
$ cat vars/testSrc.groovy
def call() {
    def tst = new org.common.CommonFuncs()
    return tst.sayHi()
}
```

pipeline script in Jenkins has:

```
@Library('jenkins-library') _
pipeline {
    agent { label 'my_servers' }

    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                testSrc()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run job, I get below error:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Test/jobs/mave/jobs/test_src/builds/8/libs/jenkins-library/vars/testSrc.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.common.CommonFuncs 
 @ line 2, column 15.
       def tst = new org.common.CommonFuncs()
                 ^
```

What is wrong in here? I am new to groovy, and this is my first attempt to create a class in shared library src/, any help is appreciated.

Comment: is it possible to have the class in src/ and use it in vars/?

Comment: Try renaming common.groovy in CommonFuncs.groovy and moving it to src/org/common/.

Comment: That worked, renamed the groovy file to match class name. thank you.

Comment: @GuidoVaccarella, can you add it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Groovy can't find your class at the path specified.

Try renaming the file common.groovy to match the class name and move it to the common folder:

```
src/org/common/CommonFuncs.groovy
```

Comment: I was creating a filename with lowercase style, but remembering what u mentioned, helped me a lot, specially the words highlighted in the jenkins documentation :
`The basename of each .groovy file should be a Groovy (~ Java) identifier, conventionally camelCased.` , reference : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#directory-structure